# SwiftUI picker Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3 in call

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a segmented picker using swiftUI. Xcode keeps telling me there are errors in the code, specifically the following 2 errors:

1. Extra arguments at positions #1, #2, #3 in call
2. Value of type 'Picker' has no member 'pickerStyle'

I have run this code in a new clean project and it compiles without issues and I get the expected result of a segmented picker.

Other swiftUI code works and compiles correctly. Additionally the deployment target is iOS 13.0.

Im not sure why this error is occurring.

**Edit -** There are no other structs or classes called Picker.

**Edit -** Running Xcode 12.3.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PickerView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedView = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: selectedView, label: Text("What is your favorite color?")) { //error 1 is on this line
            Text("Red").tag(0)
            Text("Green").tag(1)
            Text("Blue").tag(2)
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle()) //error 2 is on this line
        
    }
}
```

[Code Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9QCa.png)

Comment: Do you by any chance have another struct or class you've created named `Picker` in your project (not part of SwiftUI)?

Comment: Nope. I just checked to be doubly sure and there aren't any other structs or classes that are just called Picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is fixed variant. Tested with Xcode 12.4.

[image: demo]

```
struct PickerView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedView = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Picker(selection: $selectedView, label: Text("What is your favorite color?")) { //error 1 is on this line
            Text("Red").tag(0)
            Text("Green").tag(1)
            Text("Blue").tag(2)
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
        
    }
}
```